# Removing box shadow when image scr is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to remove the box-shadow when the the image source is empty (src=""). How can I achieve this with javascript? I think the best way is to do is to remove the class when the source is blank but I have no idea how to do that. Does anyone know?

```css
    .property {
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 290px;
      height: 200px;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      border-radius: 4px;
      text-indent: 100vw; /*to remove border when image is empty*/
      -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
      -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }
```

```html
<div class="col no-gutters">
      <img class="property" src="../accounts/report/Office.jpg">
      <div class="property-label">
        <h5>The Office</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col no-gutters">
      <img class="property" src="">
      <div class="property-label">
        <h5>The Warehouse</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use attribute selector css `.property[src=""]`

```css
.property {
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 290px;
      height: 200px;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      border-radius: 4px;
      text-indent: 100vw; /*to remove border when image is empty*/
      -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
      -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }
    .property[src=""] { 
       -webkit-box-shadow: none;
       -moz-box-shadow:none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col no-gutters">
      <img class="property" src="">
      <div class="property-label">
        <h5>The Office</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col no-gutters">
      <img class="property" src="">
      <div class="property-label">
        <h5>The Warehouse</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:not` property to only affect those with a src attribute that isn't empty.

```css
.property {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 290px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-indent: 100vw;
}
.property:not([src=""]) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="col no-gutters">
  <img class="property" src="">
  <div class="property-label">
    <h5>The Office</h5>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col no-gutters">
  <img class="property" src="">
  <div class="property-label">
    <h5>The Warehouse</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers of people are ok but I see you want make this with jquery so try this:

```js
$('.property[src=""]').css({
        "-webkit-box-shadow": "none", 
        "-moz-box-shadow": "none", 
        "box-shadow": "none"
})
```

```css
.property {
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 290px;
      height: 200px;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      border-radius: 4px;
      text-indent: 100vw; /*to remove border when image is empty*/
      -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
      -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col no-gutters">
      <img class="property" src="">
      <div class="property-label">
        <h5>The Office</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col no-gutters">
      <img class="property" src="">
      <div class="property-label">
        <h5>The Warehouse</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can do this even simpler, `$('.property[src=""]').css({"-webkit-box-shadow": "none", "-moz-box-shadow": "none", "box-shadow": "none"});`

Comment: Good idea, edited.